# combinate .slideUp and .fadeOut javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to combinate .slideUp and .fadeOut

something like this:

```
(function etc.).fadeOut(300).slideUp(100)
```

But this doesn't work

Comment: Well `.fadeOut` and `.slideUp` do the same things - hide the element. So you can't `.slideUp` on hidden element. What is the effect you want to achieve?

Comment: I suppose he wants to slide it up while fading out *at the same time*, though I'm a bit confused why the times are different then (300 vs 100). OP probably wants to look into a [custom animation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) using `.animate`.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of:

```
$("...").animate({height: 0, opacity: 0}, 300)
$("...").fadeOut(300).slideUp({duration: 100, queue: false})
$("...").fadeOut(300).slideUp(100).dequeue();
```

Comment: Nice collection. I also prefer the first one.